# How can I have leftover routes cleaned from VPC route tables

Tags: amazon-ec2

I am running instances that add routing table entries to the VPCs they run in to route certain networks to themselves.  When the instances are terminated, the routes become black hole leftovers.  I would like to know if there is a way to have the route table entries cleaned up and removed when the target instances are terminated, and if so, what is that way.